# Drupal 7 GeoField Proximity using Search API Index

Tags: search, drupal, view, openlayers

I've created a view that utilizes Search API integration and allows searching node fields. I have related content to ol_locator_location (Location) which is comprised of Address and GeoField. I have indexed the GeoField (ALL possibile iterations including WKT). I'd like to perform Proximity (Distance) searches against the indexed nodes based on the WKT data that is available. The problem is that GeoField:Proximity doesn't seem to relate well.

I'm able to add the GeoField of the related nodes and I'm able to see this on the OpenLayers map but I'm not offered any option for Proximity searching. How can I get this working?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the search_api_location module. That module adds new abilities to your geopoint filter, namely, being able to specify a point and search for nearby (proximity) places based on a radius.

Alternatively, if you like to program, you can query the solr search yourself and create the view you want using PHP or Javascript.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch

http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Spatial+Search